# Ubuntu 18.04 - what could cause a web page to not be served when Apache is running ok?

Tags: web-server, ubuntu-18.04

The company I work for has a server running Ubuntu server 18.04.  The server is connected to various cameras and performs computer vision on the images, then saves the results.

When certain events happen data is logged.  This data is viewable via a webpage that essentially acts as a friendly visual front end to presenting the data.  The webpage is not elaborate and the customer typically does not see it.  Some of the network admins at the customer sites know how to access the website and viewing the website is essential for us to monitor our product.

The problem that has been occurring lately is that the server will not serve the webpage after some irregular amount of time.  Sometimes the server will stop serving the webpage after 1/2 day, or 1 day, or 2 days, or other varying amounts of time.  I can't find that there is any regular pattern or reasoning as to when the server will stop serving the web page.

The webpage can be served independently of the vision application.  In other words, if the vision application is stopped, the webpage can still be brought up and the past vision events viewed, and the webpage will indicate that the vision application is not running currently.  The reason I'm mentioning this is to clarify that even if the vision application is not running that should not have any effect on the webpage being served.

The vision application is set up as a typical systemd service with a `.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system`.  The apache install is pretty standard for Ubuntu 18.04 server.  The webpage is a pretty basic page written with a usual LAMP stack.

The obvious 1st troubleshooting step is to do:

```
systemctl status apache2
```

This command, even when the server will not serve the webpage, indicates that `apache2` is enabled and running.  A reboot always fixes the problem (the server serves the webpage again), until the problem occurs again after some random amount of time.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to why this is happening or things I could check when it happens?  Please be gentle with any criticisms if I'm missing something obvious here as I'm mostly a vision person and I generally only do server admin and webpage stuff on an as-needed basis.

----- Edit --------------------

Dominik and Yuri Lachin, thanks for the suggestions.  It happened again this morning (could ssh into the server but the server would not serve the webpage).  Before rebooting to fix, i.e. while the server is in the state where it would not server the webpage, if I do this:

```
systemctl status apache2
```

I get this:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-12-25 18:24:09 EST; 14h ago
  Process: 16765 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2064 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 2064 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16769 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16770 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16771 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16772 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─16773 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Dec 25 18:23:57 envision systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 25 18:24:09 envision systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 26 06:25:03 envision systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 26 06:25:03 envision systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The dot just before `apache2.service2` is green.  If I do

```
journalctl -u apache2 | less
```

The end of the log looks like this:

```
Dec 21 17:51:58 server_name sudo[2758]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 21 17:51:59 server_name sudo[2758]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 21 17:52:03 server_name sudo[2777]: www-data : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/www/html/maintenance/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start portal.service
Dec 21 17:52:03 server_name sudo[2777]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 22 06:25:07 server_name systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 22 06:25:08 server_name systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 23 06:25:02 server_name systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 23 06:25:02 server_name systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 24 06:25:02 server_name systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 24 06:25:02 server_name systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 25 06:25:01 server_name systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 25 06:25:01 server_name systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 25 18:22:14 server_name systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 25 18:22:14 server_name systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Reboot --
Dec 25 18:23:57 server_name systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 25 18:24:09 server_name systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 26 06:25:03 server_name systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 26 06:25:03 server_name systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I rebooted manually around 6:30 pm the evening of December 25th, which explains the 3rd and 4th from the last lines.  I'm not sure what would have caused the "Reloading" and "Reloaded" events at 6:25 am on the 26th.

So following Yuri's suggestion I checked MySQL and found it was not running:

```
systemctl status mysql.service

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2018-12-26 06:04:31 EST; 3h 10min ago
 Main PID: 1989 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 25 18:23:56 envision systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Dec 25 18:24:19 envision systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Dec 26 06:04:27 envision systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Dec 26 06:04:31 envision systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

The circle before `mysql.service` is black.  If I do:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Then the website works again.  I guess I have to figure out why MySQL stops and/or set it in systemd to at least auto-restart if it stops.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the logs at /etc/log/apache2/ ?
Also, what kind of webpage is it, are there any PHP scripts running?

Comment: If your appication uses database for web page generation you also need to check the status of database (mysql ?) - is it running, does it accept connections, are there long-running/stuck queries, etc.